Is Orberg's Caesaris Commentarii de Bello Gallico heavily adapted from C. Julius Caesar's Gallic War?
I hope this message finds you well. I am interested in reading sections of Caesar's Gallic War and came across this edition:

Commentarii de bello Gallico: https://search.worldcat.org/en/title/1376404740

Could anyone clarify whether this edition is adapted from the original text or if it presents a faithful rendering of Caesar's Latin? I plan to use it for a course and want to ensure it closely resembles the original work. The description mentions that it is "abridged," but I assume this refers to the selection of passages rather than a compromise in accuracy.
Thank you very much for your assistance!

I have checked a paragraph from the book against the Loeb edition, and it is identical (except for punctuation, diacritics, and a typing-mistake in the Loeb). It was this passage, from book IV:

His constitutis rebus, et consilio cum legatis et quaestore communicato 'ne quem diem pugnae praetermitteret', opportunissima res accidit quod postridie eius diei mane, eadem et perfidia et simulatione usi, Germani frequentes, omnibus principibus maioribusque natu adhibitis, ad eum in castra venerunt, simul, ut dicebatur, sui purgandi causa 'quod contra atque esset dictum et ipsi petissent, proelium pridie commisissent' simul ut, si quid possent, de indutiis fallendo impetrarent. Quos sibi Caesar oblatos gavisus, illos retineri iussit, ipse omnes copias castris eduxit equitatumque, quod recenti proelio perterritum esse existimabat, agmen subsequi iussit.

So my impression is that it is not adapted, but it is just various passages from books I, IV, and V 'as Caesar wrote them'.

According to the publisher's website, 'This text includes abridged annotated versions of Julius Caesar's firsthand account of the Gallic Wars Books I, IV and V.' Based on this, I'd agree that it's excerpted but not adapted in any way.
